# Manhwa/manhua where the main character is tricked into eating a fire seed

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

The main character has a system where, for example, whenever he gets hit, he gets these points to help him level up, but he needs to get a lot of points so he can upgrade things like his body defense.  The main character is tricked by an old man to eat a red/fire seed thing. He eats it, and his whole body turns red and he starts getting system notifications like "1+ pain/burning 1+ pain/burning."

The main character is a masochist and purposely will hurt himself just to get points. For example, he gets beat up by a gang of people just for points.  He can use the points to make himself stronger; in the story line he had, I think, elementary-level power but intermediate-level body defense.

He got the body defense by tricking these people who wanted to rob his house because they thought he was dead. He tricked them into thinking he was stronger than them and used the points from tricking them to upgrade his body. With his system, he is not restrained by the world, where he has to have intermediate-level power to have intermediate-level body defense. He also upgrades his cultivation technique.

It's in a wuxia kind of world.

Comment: If you are the poster of [this question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/yoerjs/need_help_finding_a_manhwa/) you should note that the question has also been posted elsewhere.

Comment: what do you mean? i posted it on reddit to see if more people can help me find it

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your question will get more attention, and is more likely to get a useful answer, if the title is descriptive of the story you are looking for.  The tags already tell everyone that you're looking for the name of a story, so you don't need to say that.

Comment: People here will do searches (like I did) to see if they can tease out pages that match your question.  They will immediately stumble on the question on Reddit, so it's polite to say you've posted the question there too.  That way everyone who is trying to help doesn't have to go to the Reddit post and find the answer isn't there.

Comment: In case you were wondering why I edited the title, it's because alot of questions are initially posted with titles along the lines of "need help finding a Manhwa/manhua", and if we don't edit those titles to make them more specific to the plot/premise being described, then it becomes very hard to tell these questions apart from the titles alone. Also, the inclusion the the [story-identification] tag already lets other users know that this is a story-ID question, so it's redundant to state that in the title as well.

Comment: so if the title is more descriptive it will help me find my answer better? is that what you are trying to say

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll help in terms of finding the correct story. It certainly won't decrease the likelihood of that though, and it's better for the site for story-ID questions to have distinctive titles, rather than generic ones like _"I need help finding a book/movie/manga"_.

Comment: thank you for explaining